# perform different operations on same options menu item

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I have a options menu item for creating bookmark.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        saveBookState();
        finish();
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_bookmark) {
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_filled);
        Adapter adapter = (Adapter) mViewPager.getAdapter();
        PageFragment fragment = (PageFragment) adapter.instantiateItem(mViewPager, mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
        fragment.getBookmarkContent();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Bookmark Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I want to perform another operation on same bookmark button like when click on first time it will add bookmark, at the same position on clicking second time it will remove that bookmark as well as change the filled icon with empty icon.

So, how I going to perform two different operations on same options menu item?

Comment: How do you usually do one thing or another? Hint: `if... else...`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a flag, then check using if(){} in onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){}
for example:

```
Boolean flag = true;
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
    saveBookState();
    finish();
} else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_bookmark) {
    if(flag){// add bookmark
     //make flag=false;
}else{// remove bookmark //make flag=true;}
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MenuBuilder instead of onOptionsItemSelected method

First create Overflow icon in Action bar and perform click for it.

```
    overflowIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                final MenuBuilder menuBuilder = new MenuBuilder(context);
                MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(context);
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_item, menuBuilder);

// check with some boolean variable or shared preference
                if(condition for check bookmark or not){
// if bookmark then show title as 'remove bookmark'
                    menuBuilder.findItem(R.id.menu_bookmark).setTitle("remove bookmark");

                }else{
                  menuBuilder.findItem(R.id.menu_bookmark).setTitle("bookmark");
                }


                MenuPopupHelper optionsMenu = new MenuPopupHelper(context, menuBuilder, v);

// for show icon as define in menu then remove comment below 
//                optionsMenu.setForceShowIcon(true);  


                menuBuilder.setCallback(new MenuBuilder.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder menu, MenuItem item) {


                if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_bookmark){


                            if(condition for check bookmark or not){
                                // do code for cancel bookmark

                            }else{
                                 // do code for bookmark
                            }

                        }
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onMenuModeChange(MenuBuilder menu) {}
                });


                // Display the menu
                optionsMenu.show();
            }
        });
```

For menu_item.xml in Menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_bookmark"
            android:orderInCategory="200"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="bookmark" />

</menu>
```